# Inserting string at a certain point in a larger set of text

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is insert a string `<a href=\"{href}\">{text}</a>` in a larger wall of article text but the large wall of text looks like:

`{word|word|word} {word|word|word} {word|word|word} {word|word|word|word} etc`

I'm looking to insert `<a href=\"{href}\">{text}</a>";`  randomly, but it has to be between one of these `} {` curly brackets so it will look like `} <a href=\"{href}\">{text}</a> {`

The way my code is now it just inserts anywhere (i know i need to add the logic to look between the brackets) which is where my issue is, i'm not sure the best way to do this.

**Code:**

```
        public static string GetAndInjectAhrefLinkIntoArticle(string article, string href, string text) {
            string injectedArticle = null;
            try {
                var rnd = new Random();
                string stringToInsert = $"<a href=\"{href}\">{text}</a>";

                int length = article.Length;
                if (length > 0)
                {
                    int pos = rnd.Next(0, length);
                    injectedArticle = article.Insert(pos, stringToInsert);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
            return injectedArticle;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Collect the indexes of the "} {" substrings, select one of them randomly, then insert the link there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use `pos = article.IndexOf("} {", pos) + 1` after you pick a random `pos`, to find the location of the next `} {`, and when you insert, insert an extra space at the start of `stringToInsert`..

If IndexOf returns -1, you might have tried too near the end; you could either:

- Accept it will insert at the start (-1 becomes 0 when +1'd so it's valid)
- Go again with another random (i.e. use a `while(pos == 0) ...`, or
- Look at using LastIndexOf to give a more suitable upper bound for your random so it will always find the last `} {`